# Is it possible to use Caffe to classify text?

Tags: machine-learning, convolution

I'm trying to build a sentence classifier using Caffe, for example the following dataset:

1 -> **'Fell energy at my home'**

2 -> **'I liked the city's new buses'**

3 -> **'It has a hole in the road in front of my house'**

4 -> **'The new public soccer field is perfect'**

I have to classify those sentences like: **infrastructure**, **recreation**, **security** and so on.

How can I do this using Caffe? What logic should I use for this? Like labels and to transform my text to **lmdb** that can be read by **Caffe**?